# How do you troubleshoot K8s app failures?

Tags: performance, kubernetes, causality

My team is looking to better understand current workflows associated with troubleshooting and remediating application failures in Kubernetes environments. How do you typically go about troubleshooting K8s app failures? What are the biggest bottlenecks or frustrations in the process?

Additional context:
We’re building a platform that determines causality and automates the detection and remediation of application failures. It’s currently in early access; we’re looking for input from this community to make sure it solves a real pain. If you’re interested in testing out the early access product and providing feedback, you can sign up [here](https://www.causely.io/early-access/).  (This is certainly not meant to be vendor spam – please comment if inappropriate and I can delete.)

An example that we've tried is documented here: https://www.causely.io/blog/managing-database-connection-failures/

Comment: It sounds like an interesting project, but I don't think this question is appropriate here: it's mostly an opinion question, which are explicitly off-topic because there's no way to identify "the correct answer".